# Creating a notebook that has cells of a certain style password protected

Tags: dynamic

I am teaching students how to use Mathematica.  I want to create a problem set that has cells with a certain style (probably Input or some new style that is a variant of Input) locked down so that the students can not see them at all or just see an unevaluatable placeholder instead.  But I also want a cell within the notebook that permits someone with a password (like me) to make these hidden cells visible and evaluatable.

Extra credit: it would be cool if I could relock these cells so that they reverted to their hidden form.

Concession: Maybe the unlocking cell does not have to be in the notebook but could be a function in an external notebook that worked on the problem set notebook.

Right now I accomplish the basic idea by having two notebooks, one with the answers and one without them.  But this is ugly and leads to synchronization errors as I change my mind.

Ideas welcome. Obviously, simpler is better.

Comment: Are your students knowledgable enough to peek at the cell expression?

Comment: Your current approach of having two notebooks could be made robust by putting a button at the top of the master Q/A notebook that generates a question-only notebook when you need to distribute the questions.

Comment: Yes, my students are probably smart enough to peek at the cell expression.  Or at least I will give them credit for being that industrious.

Comment: Yes, JxB, I can always Option-Select and then delete the Input cells or whatever Style I give to cells that Students Should Not See. But I still wonder if there is not a one-document solution.  I suppose the issue is going to be whether we can come up with a one-document solution that is simple enough so that the document-management advantages outweigh the extra overhead.

Comment: With TaggingRules and Encode and so on one can probably do this, but it is quite some work I guess ...

Comment: perhaps have your group of cells by default closed with `Selectable->False` and have a button in the notebook which when pressed asks for a password and if correct the cell options are changed to open and `Selectable->True`. The underlying cell expression is still exposed of course but doing this means it needs a bit more work to get at it.

Comment: What are those hidden cells supposed to do?

Answer (score 9):

Here's an idea following up on the master-notebook model.

The master notebook has two additional cell styles: `AnswerInput` and `AnswerOutput`. You can write the questions as you like, using `ItemNumbered`, `Text`, or whatever style except those two new styles. You put your answer code in an `AnswerInput` cell, and evaluate it. Set the output cell to style `AnswerOutput`.

[image: Master Notebook]

The master notebook has a button at the top, which you can copy for each assignment, that generates the question document. You distribute that notebook to the students, but only ever have to edit the master. Consequently the question notebook is automatically synchronized to the master notebook.

[image: Question Notebook]

The question notebook does not contain the `Button`, and your answers are replaced with a placeholder `Input` cell.

I'm inclined to do it this way because

1. I don't have to remember and protect an additional password.
2. Since there is no password prompt, students will not be distracted trying to guess the password.
3. The notebook itself is not subject to attack for purposes of cheating, since the answers are not in the notebook.

Here is the code for the button. Evaluate it at the top of a new notebook, and double-click on the button cell frame at the right to hide the code. Note: you need to add "ButtonCode" to the CellTags option on this cell (from the Cell menu) to ensure the button is not included in the question notebook.

```
(* Click this button to generate a notebook without answers *)
Button["Create question notebook", 
 Module[{copy, cursorposition = NotebookSelection[]},
  (* Copy the current notebook, inheriting the stylesheet *)
  copy = CreateDocument[{}, 
    NotebookFileName -> 
     FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "Questions.nb"}], 
    StyleDefinitions -> CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], 
      StyleDefinitions]];
  NotebookWrite[copy, 
   (SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, Notebook, 
     AutoScroll -> False]; NotebookRead[EvaluationNotebook[]])];
  (* Return cursor to its initial position *)
  SelectionMove[cursorposition, After, Cell];
  (* Remove all "AnswerOutput"-Style cells *)
  NotebookFind[copy, "AnswerOutput", All, CellStyle];
  NotebookDelete[copy];
  (* Replace all "AnswerInput"-Style cells with a placeholder Input cell, framed with a Gray border *)
  NotebookFind[copy, "AnswerInput", All, CellStyle];
  Scan[
   NotebookWrite[#, Cell[BoxData["(* Your solution *)\n"], 
      "Input", CellFrame -> {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}, 
      CellFrameColor -> Gray]] &, SelectedCells[copy]];
  (* Remove the button code *)
  NotebookFind[copy, "ButtonCode", All, CellTags];
  NotebookDelete[copy];
  (* Return cursor to its initial position *)
  SelectionMove[cursorposition, After, Cell];
 ], ImageSize -> All]
```

Add these two styles to the notebook's stylesheet:

```
Cell[StyleData["AnswerInput", StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["Input"]], GeneratedCellStyles->{"Output"->"AnswerOutput"}, MenuSortingValue->10000]
```

and

```
Cell[StyleData["AnswerOutput", StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["Output"]], MenuSortingValue->10000]
```

The question notebook will keep a copy of any `Output` cells from your master, so you can include `Output` in the questions themselves. When you evaluate `AnswerInput` cells, however, the outputs are styled `AnswerOutput`, and those are removed from the question notebook.

Comment: This looks very useful (although question 3 looks kind of challenging). I'll give it a try and comment here later on what I discover.  It does have the virtue of simplicity even if it does lead to two notebooks.  Thanks very much for your efforts.  I am quite impressed.

Comment: @SethJ.Chandler I've found out how to make the AnswerInput styles automatically evaluate to AnswerOutput. See updated stylesheet definitions. No more manual editing of the outputs.

Answer (score 7):

I don't claim this will do everything you want, but this [presentation by Jason Harris on Advanced Typesetting](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/8010/) includes a program that will Encrypt code and allow it to be unlocked with a short and simple password.

Apparently it was used live during a workshop presentation to encourage those in attendance to attempt the problem(s) at hand without first seeing the solution(s). (Did anyone on here attend??)

Note: You may have to dismiss a message box when launching the notebook. Everything works fine for me on v9.

Comment: That's a nice presentation and looks like it should be sufficient for the OP's needs.

Answer (score 5):

This is a start that could be turned into a style and a package, and improved, etc.

First, some function to encrypt a string with a key. I'm not good at this, I only knew how to do it with `Encode`

```
encode[expr_, password_String] :=
 With[{fnameSource = FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "encrSource"}],
       fnameDest = FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "encrDest"}]},
  Block[{buff},
   Put[Unevaluated[buff = expr], fnameSource];
   Encode[fnameSource, fnameDest, password];
   With[{res = StringJoin@Import[fnameDest, {"Binary", "Character8"}]},
    Scan[DeleteFile, {fnameSource, fnameDest}];
    res
    ]
   ]]
```

To decode

```
decode[expr_String, password_String] := 
 With[{fname = FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "decr"}]},
      Export[fname, Characters@expr, {"Binary", "Character8"}];
      Block[{buff},
       Quiet@Check[Get[fname, password], buff = $Failed];
   With[{res = buff},
    DeleteFile@fname;
    res]
   ]]
```

The idea is simple: to provide a button in a `CellFrameLabel`, that encrypts or decrypts the cell's content

Let's overload our previous functions, letting them take a cell object

```
encode[co_CellObject] := 
 With[{pass = InputString["Please, enter the password"]},
  CurrentValue[co, {TaggingRules, "encoded"}] = True;
  NotebookWrite[co,
   Replace[NotebookRead[co], 
    Cell[data_, opts___] :> 
     Cell[BoxData@
       ToBoxes@Interpretation["Hidden cell", 
         Evaluate@encode[data, pass]], opts]]];
  SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], After, Cell];
  ]

decode[co_CellObject] := 
 With[{pass = InputString["Please, enter the password"]},
  With[{newCell = Replace[
      NotebookRead[co],
      Cell[BoxData[int_], opts___] :> 
       Cell[decode[ToExpression@int, pass], opts]]},
   (CurrentValue[co, {TaggingRules, "encoded"}] = False;
   NotebookWrite[co, newCell];
   SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], After, Cell]) /; 
    MatchQ[newCell, Cell[Except[$Failed], ___]]]
  ]

decode::fail = "Failed to decode cell";
decode[_CellObject] := (Message[decode::fail]; $Failed /; False)
```

These are the options an "encryptable cell" should have. Just a tagging rule with the state (encrypted or not encrypted), and the cell frame label specifications.

```
opts = Sequence[
  CellFrameLabels -> {{None, None}, {None, ToBoxes@Dynamic[
       CurrentValue[{TaggingRules, "encoded"}] /. {
          False :> {"Encode", encode},
          True :> {"Decode", decode}} /. {butName_, fun_} :>
         Button[butName, 
          fun[SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, 
            EvaluationCell]; First@SelectedCells[]], 
          Method -> "Queued"]]}}, 
  TaggingRules -> {"encoded" -> False}];
```

So, for example, try

```
CellPrint@ExpressionCell[28 f[9], "Output", opts]
```

or

```
CellPrint@TextCell["The answer is 8", "Text", opts]
```

You can put this into a stylesheet, and the functions into a package.

Comment: It's probably nicer to use a palette or a docked cell than a style and `CellFrameLabels`. It should be quite easy to do from this code

Comment: I'm also going to give this idea a shot and will report back on how it goes.  Your idea of putting the cell to be encoded into a notebook and then using the built-in Encode function is clever, though I wish Wolfram Research would have a more general Encode function that worked on things other than a notebook.  Thanks for your work on this problem.

Comment: No problem @SethJ.Chandler. I probably will end up putting this in a palette for myself too: select a cell or piece of text, click, password, and hidden.

Comment: @SethJ.Chandler I'll probably make the palette later and ping you to share it

Comment: @SethJ.Chandler What do you mean by more general. Right now you can encode .m files or any text file, e.g.:`Export["test.txt","secrect","Text"];Encode["test.txt","test.enc",MachineID->$MachineID];FilePrint@"test.enc"`

Comment: @Rolf -- Thanks. To Encode, though, I have to put it into a file.  I would like to be able to take any Mathematica expression and say Encode[exp,"myCleverPassword"] without the overhead of exporting to a file.  Alternatively, perhaps Compress could be expanded to have a "Password" option and Compress would produce an encrypted version of the input.  One could add a Method option to permit different types of encryption.  Uncompress could then be augmented to take additional arguments that inverted the encryption.