# Lock .nb cells of a file

Tags: printing, security

I'm working on my research and I defined a few function that I don't want anyone to take from my code. And I must submit the Mathematica file to a public place.
Is there any way to lock my nb file by a password or at least hide some cells completely but execute them when the Mathematica code runs?

One last thing, is there any way to save the output of Print command into variable?

Comment: sorry it should be (nb) mathematica files extension.

Comment: Is this the same question [How to distribute proprietary Mathematica code](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1571/5478)?

Comment: Please ask *one* clear question within one post.  If you have multiple questions, ask them in separate posts.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to make some functions available for use, but you do not want the users to be able to read your source code:

- [Put the functions into a package](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/132960/12)
- Make sure that all the functions are [`ReadProtected`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReadProtected.html) and [`Locked`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Locked.html)
- [`Encode`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Encode.html) the package

Comment: But hiding your research code this way is not a very nice thing to do, especially if your research is publicly funded.

Comment: If there is one thing that sites like these have tought me, that would be the importance of non-interested sharing. (+1)

Comment: Actually i must give the code to public, which is fine but i need to register the function first. which i cant do now. the equations are for my adviser he asked me to do so until he register it then he will publish them.

Answer (score 4):

A `Cell` can be made so that it is not possible to delete using the computer keyboard or the edit menu. To do this, use `SetOptions[<cell_in_question>, Deletable->False]`, doing this manually using Cell > Show Expression, or make a style in your notebook's stylesheet that with that option set.

If you would like to make it so one can't edit your cells using the keyboard, you can set `Editable->False` which can also be done in the Cell > Cell Properties menu.

Note that these cells can still be deleted by unsetting this option or by manually removing them in the `Notebook` expression and using `NotebookPut`. I'm sure there are other ways to do this as well that I simply don't know.

To fully lock a cell, consider reading through [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17563/creating-a-notebook-that-has-cells-of-a-certain-style-password-protected/17590#17590) to get ideas.

As for storing print in a variable,
`Print` creates a new cell with the style `"Print"`. You can change this to `"Input"` using, for example, Command-9 on a Mac. This will make it work like a normal `"Input"` cell.

If you want to store the value from `Print` in a variable, simply store it before printing or, if you absolutely must do it at run-time, wrap the following hacky function around your code:

```
$printCache = {};
cachedPrint[code_] :=
  Internal`InheritedBlock[{Print},
   Unprotect@Print;
   Print[stuff__] /; (! TrueQ@$printCachingOverload) :=

    Block[{$printCachingOverload = True},
     AppendTo[$printCache, {stuff}];
     Print[stuff]
     ];
   Protect@Print;
   code
   ];
cachedPrint~SetAttributes~HoldFirst;
```

Then use it like, say:

```
cachedPrint[Do[someSuperCoolFunction[x]; Print[x, " etc."], {x, 10}]]
```

It will print everything, but all the arguments to print will be stored in `$printCache` e.g:

```
In[33]:= $printCache

Out[33]= {{1, " etc."}, {2, " etc."}, {3, " etc."}, {4, " etc."}, {5, 
  " etc."}, {6, " etc."}, {7, " etc."}, {8, " etc."}, {9, 
  " etc."}, {10, " etc."}}
```

And just to check that the `DownValues` we set on `Print` have not been saved:

```
In[34]:= DownValues@Print

Out[34]= {}
```

This is not the best way to do this. It's much easier to just store the value yourself, but if you have to capture it you can do it like this.

However, this kind of strategy is useful for capturing and rerouting messages by applying a similar overload strategy to `Message` and capturing pieces of `MessageName`. Of course, even better there is to use `` GeneralUtilities`WithMessageHandler `` and work with the `Failure` object.